# Why does Yii allow me to access the private $this->_property, with $this->property?

Tags: yii

I'm not sure what's happening here, perhaps someone has a clue:

On my layout I have this:

```
<div id="main-content" class="<?= $this->getMainClass(); ?>">
```

On components>controller class I have this:

```
 private $_mainCssClass;

    public function setMainCssClass($className) {

     if (is_string($className)) {
        $this->_mainCssClass = $className;
     } else {
        quickDump($className);
     }
    }

    public function getMainCssClass() {
     return $this->_mainClass;
    }
```

What I'm not getting is, despite the fact that we are using accessors, and the mainCssClass property has an underscore and it's declared private, I can access it trough:

```
$this->MainCssClass;
```

The same as: `$this->getMainCssClass()`

Why is that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't access the private `_mainCssClass` but rather `getMainCssClass()` which is a public method. So you are allowed to call this method from outside and you can also access `mainCssClass` (which is just a shorthand for `getMainCssClass()`).

And from `getMainCssClass()` you are allowed to access any private variable inside the same class. There's no restriction that you could not return the value of a private variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a shorter syntax, more convenient to read and write.

See the [Yii Framework Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#component-property) for details and the [source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/base/CComponent.php#L107) for some impressions about the "magic".

Comment: thanks a lot for that source code reference. Quite interesting. I opt to declare Michael Hartl as an answer because, it actually make me understand that we are NOT accessing the private property but getMainCssClass (that I actually tested and see that was the case). Again, thanks.